# mongodb populate flat file results?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am trying to remove old files from the file system
The file list is maintained in mongoDb collection like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a39215953f77968789d692"),
    "className" : "com.xerox.model.ModuleDocument",
    "documentId" : "0000001643",
    "documentDate" : ISODate("2017-05-11T04:00:00.000Z"),
    "documentType" : "PRINTER_VALIDATION_2017",
    "module" : "PRINTERS",
    "printerId" : "1002563",
    "origFileName" : "0000001643.JPG",
    "isDeleted" : true
}
```

But when I query the DB using the mongo shell

```
 db.getCollection('xerox_documents').find({"isDeleted":true})
```

The result is displayed as JSON, 
Is it possible to get the results in flat text format? 
The desired output is something like:

```
DEL c:\DOCS\PRINTERS\PRINTER_VALIDATION_2017\0000001643.JPG  
DEL c:\DOCS\PRINTERS\PRINTER_VALIDATION_2017\0000001643.JPG
```

Comment: can you please explain more... which field you want to be in text format?

Comment: any field if you can show me how, I can build the rest

Comment: just loop over the results with a `forEach` and use `print` function to format the string.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara can you provide a sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not forget that mongodb script are closely related to js script.

```
db.getCollection('xerox_documents').find({"isDeleted": true}).forEach(elem => {
    print(`DEL c:\\DOCS\\${elem.module}\\${elem.documentType}\\${elem.origFileName}`);
});
```

You can use `print()` to format your results as raw text. The `find()` function returns a `cursor`, which is a pointer to the result query. Think of it as an iterator on which you can call the `forEach` function, that has the same signature as the `Array.forEach` in js.

Looping over a `Cursor` can be made in other 2 ways:

- Manually calling `next()` until `hasNext()` is true. It's a typical scheme for an Iterable.
- Using `Cursor.toArray()` to generate an array that stores all the results into  an array. Watch out because they are loaded into RAM.

The lambda function I have put as argument in `forEach` is interpreted as a full-fledged js function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) to concatenate any field in the collection

```
db.getCollection('xerox_documents').aggregate([
  { "$match": { "isDeleted": true }},
  { "$project": {
    "origFileName": {
      "$concat": [ "c:\DOCS\PRINTERS\PRINTER_VALIDATION_2017\", "$origFileName" ]
    }
  }}
])
```